# Which online form builders offer conditional logic/branching?

Tags: forms

I have a survey with the following form fields:

1. Country
2. Age
3. Male/Female
4. Undergraduate/Graduate
5. Question?

   - Yes
   - No
6. If No, what about this and that?

   - Yes
   - No

Google Forms and SurveyMonkey don't seem to allow things like the above. For question one I could ask, "What country are you from?" with a textbox as an answer section and work around it.

But how do I go about creating questions five and six? I am not able to figure out how to do it except for having one more question that says "If your answer to the previous question was No, then blah blah (else skip this question)".

Any suggestions, apart from creating my own custom website with JavaScript and a backend database?

Answer (score 3):

The feature you're looking for is called 'conditional logic' or 'branching'. Many hosted form services offer it:

- Survey Monkey has a feature called ['question skip logic'](http://help.surveymonkey.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/39/kw/conditional%20questions/session/L3NpZC9RYzJSQXJHaw%3D%3D) that allows you to show and hide later questions based on the response to earlier ones.
- [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com) calls it ['skip logic and branching'](http://www.wufoo.com/2010/03/09/good-king-wenceslaus-wufoo-now-has-conditional-logic-and-branching/).
- [Formstack](http://www.formstack.com) calls it ['conditional logic'](http://www.formstack.com/conditional-logic.html).
- Google Forms has a basic branching/conditional logic system that lets you direct respondents to a different page depending upon their answer to a certain question. They call it ['page navigation'](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/07/page-navigation-in-google-forms.html). It's not quite as advanced as the other services listed above.

For your 'Country' field, you could use a drop-down with a [full list of countries](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/376). For your male/female and graduate/undergraduate fields, you could use a radio button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me tell you, you have asked a good question. The feature that you want to add in a form is basically called a **Conditional Logic** or **Logic & Branching**, where question are inter-related according to the true/false of a conditions.

I personally suggest you some online form building app that I found it effective and allow you to implement any type of control logic you want.

1. [Formstack](http://www.formstack.com/features/conditional-logic)
2. [FormGet](http://www.formget.com/)
3. [Wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com/)